# IOException: The process cannot access the file when calling CacheManager.GetData

Tags: c#, enterprise-library

We are using Enterprise Library CacheManager for caching . All is well when we run only one instances of the application. But when multiple instances of the app are opened, CacheManager.GetData("key") throws an error **"IOException: The process cannot access the file 'CachePartition2.8\1133903271\LA' because it is being used by another process."**.
what is the reason behind this?
Our configuration is as follows:

```
<cachingConfiguration defaultCacheManager="Cache Manager">
<cacheManagers>
  <add expirationPollFrequencyInSeconds="60" maximumElementsInCacheBeforeScavenging="1000" 
    numberToRemoveWhenScavenging="10" backingStoreName="Isolated Storage"
    name="Cache Manager" />
</cacheManagers>
<backingStores>
  <add partitionName="CachePartition2.8" encryptionProviderName="" 
    type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching.BackingStoreImplementations.IsolatedStorageBackingStore, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
    name="Isolated Storage" />
</backingStores>
```

Comment: Read [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648661.aspx), update your question with *anything* that's relevant to the backing store solution you selected.

Comment: @HansPassant we have configured the cache and backing storage as follows:<backingStores>
      <add partitionName="CachePartition2.8" encryptionProviderName="" 
        type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching.BackingStoreImplementations.IsolatedStorageBackingStore, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
        name="Isolated Storage" />
    </backingStores>

Comment: Changing BackStore type from isolatedstorage to nullstorage worked in our case. Tx to @HansPassant. Now my question is: Can isolatedstorage supports MultiInstance of same application? Does this issue occurred due to access of same cache by two or more instance of same application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing BackStore type from isolatedstorage to nullstorage worked in our case. Thanks to Hans Passant